# Is "driving the reins" used as a deliberately erroneous phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, humor

In her [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) introducing Blog Overflow, the estimable Rebecca Chernoff committed the following, uh, sentence:

> Have someone driving the reigns.

After cringing (read: screaming in pain) and [posting a comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/#comment-59653) to gently point out the error (read: ranting and raving), I started having second thoughts. Clearly, Rebecca knows how to write. Clearly, she knows what *reign* means, and that *reins* are the agents, not the objects, of driving. So maybe this is a *deliberate* mistake, something along the lines of "[Six degrees of Kevin Bacon](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29576/1547)" or (somewhat controversially) "[Could care less](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/706/could-couldnt-care-less)".

Is this/can this be interpreted as a deliberate mashup of "holding the reins" and "driving the car" and "reigning"?

Comment: Sounds like a mixed metaphor to me, which is definitely a device that is used as humor (sometimes), though I wouldn't compare it to "could care less" as I'm not sure that's ever really *funny* as a result of purposeful intent. I've heard mixed metaphors such as "skating on hot water".

Comment: This reminds me of one of the most tooth-grinding-inducing misspellings that I know of: "reign in spending".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is a deliberate mistake, because Rebecca Chernoff corrected [her blog:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)

> **•Have someone holding the reins.** This person doesn’t need to be the one writing all the posts, just someone that helps coordinate who is writing what and when it is getting posted.

In short, I think it was a typo!

Comment: +1 Just noticed this myself.  Although I can see "driving the reigns" catching on, now :)

Comment: Oh, dear. What have I started?

Comment: Never mind, at least you gave me information regarding the blogs...

Answer (score 1):

While I am not privy to the author's state of mind, my guess would be that the awkwardly mixed metaphor was deliberate and the misspelling was a momentary lapse. It happens to the best of us -- I used "your" for "you're" for the very first time in my life (and I've been writing for about forty-seven years now) three days ago, on the public intarwebs, in a non-editable context and with my real name attached for posterity.

Comment: Your kidding! How embarrassing. ;)

Comment: @Renesis: I really should thwack you, but (a) it's not, technically, a pun, and (b) I'm laughing too hard to grab the ruler. :D

Comment: @Martha - you disapprove of paronomasiacs? We really can't help it, you know, and there are know known drugs that don't make our condition worse. We especially transcend dental medication.

Comment: @Stan, see, now *that* gets a resounding THWACK!!!

Comment: Geez, Louise, another slip. "Know" for "no". Dementia isn't as much fun as they said it would be in the brochure. I wouldn't mind if I couldn't notice it...

Comment: Oh, and that's what we live for. It would be better if people held their noses and ran screaming from the room, but that reaction doesn't translate well online.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed (or inverted) metaphors are sometimes used for emphasis. For instance, instead of saying "The early bird catches the worm," a colleague once raised eyebrows by saying "The early worm catches the bird."